# Why cannot replace (.) in pandas replace

Tags: python, pandas

so i have a data that contain something like `. Nomor cs tidak dapat dihubungi . Tempat saya tidak bisa pickup padahal dekat kantor pos . Tidak ada panduan co`
But when I try replace it by `regex=True` or `regex=False` it didnt change anything.In my dataframe also have some emoticon is this also make it failed?.This is my code

```
data = pd.read_excel('pos indonesia.xlsx')
data1 = data['content']
datacek = data1.replace({'.':'',',':'','"':''},regex =True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is special regex expression for match any character, need escape it by `\`:

```
datacek = data1.replace({'\.':'',',':'','"':''},regex =True)
```

Or:

```
datacek = data1.replace('[\.:"]','',regex =True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data = pd.read_excel('pos indonesia.xlsx')
data1 = data['content']
datacek = data1.replace('\.', '', regex=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a regex expression, escape it:

```
datacek = data1.replace({'\.':'',',':'','"':''},regex =True)
```